# regex to identify failures in log

Tags: regex, shell

I have a log file. I want to scan the occurrences of the string

"RC = x"
If there is >=1 one occurrence where RC = 0 is not TRUE then I want to flag it as failure

Can I do this as shell function?

Comment: What have you written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grep for this:

```
grep -q "RC = [^0]" logfile && {
  echo "Logfile is a failure"
  other commands
  exit
}
```

The `-q` puts `grep` into silence mode: no output, the `[^0]` matches any non-zero value for RC.  Grep will return a failure status if no matches are found and a success status if any are. The `&&` is a conditional "and" so if there are any non-zero values for RC, then the grep will succeed and the test is a failure.

Alternately, you can put the `grep` into an `if` statement.  In this case:

```
if grep -s "RC = [^0]" logfile
then
  echo "Logfile is a failure"
else
  echo "Logfile is a success"
fi
```

See `man grep` for more grep options.

Comment: `-s` only suppresses error messages, but the matching lines are still printed. Did you maybe mean `-q`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. You are correct.  I have adjusted my answer.  Thank you.